# Guice post execution method interception

Tags: aop, guice

In Guice, is there a way for my `MethodInterceptor::invoke` implementation to be invoked *after* the intercepted method is executed (and not immediately before)?

I've added the current code to my `AbstractModule`:

```java
bindInterceptor(Matchers.subclassesOf(InterceptedClass.class), Matchers.annotatedWith(MyMethodAnnotation.class), new MyMethodInterceptor());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To execute code after the method invocation in an interceptor (this applies not just to Guice), you have to use a try/finally combination:

```java
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
   try {
      // code run before execution

      return invocation.proceed();
   } finally {
      // code run after execution
   }
}
```